# Edit marginpar command through whole document

Tags: formatting, align, marginpar

I'm finding myself doing the following on every margin paragraph:

```
\marginpar{\raggedright \scriptsize <content here>}
```

Is there a way to set the align and script size for every margin paragraph in the document?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do it by redefining `\@marginparreset`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@marginparreset}{%
  \reset@font\scriptsize
  \raggedright
  \@setminipage
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\let\MPar\marginpar
\renewcommand\marginpar[2][]{\MPar[\raggedright\scriptsize#1]{\raggedright\scriptsize#1}}
```

- It makes sense to load package `ragged2e` and then `\RaggedRight` instead of `\raggedright`. It allows hyphenation.
- And also using package `marginnote` with the same command name will be a good choice.